# ReactJS Exposing normal folder structure even after build

Tags: reactjs, npm-scripts

Today I see a weird thing after build a ReactJS app. when I checking in the browser after builded files it's exposing my raw folder structure. It should not expose the directory.

[image]

I see some StackOverflow saying that `"homepage" : "."` in `package.json` will solve, someone saying `"start_url" : "/"` need to change in `manifest.json`. but nothing is working for me. Any way to solve this.

Comment: Are you using Create React App and have you ejected?

Comment: create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this because you're running this project locally.

When you run a project locally, it doesn't use the `prod` version of your app. It uses the `dev` version which isn't optimized for `production`. This is done to help you out with debugging during the development phase of your project.

If you deployed the app, the deployment would be using the `build` output (and not your local build, like you see here).

**Note:** If you're still experiencing this issue then your bundler (if you've ejected a CreateReactApp, then I'm referring to `webpack`) needs proper configuration and you'd need to provide us with more information.

Comment: I am using built-in create react app. I have not configured anything in webpack or ejected. What I did, I separate the build directory after the build process completed. and the issue persist even I deployed. let me know what other information you need?

Comment: is there any explicit way, so that I can instruct to use production version?